# java attempting to assign weaker access privilege error

Tags: java, compiler-errors, selenium-rc

```
[javac] U:\dms-webui-testing\test-java\dmswebui\CR\TestLogin.java:16: until() in  cannot override until() in com.thoughtworks.selenium.Wait; attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
```

I am getting above error for a fairly simple code:

```
package dmswebui.CR;

import org.infineta.webui.selenium4j.MainTestCase;

public class TestLogin extends MainTestCase {

  @Override
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    startSeleniumSession("ChromeDriver", "somesite");
  }

  public void testMethod() throws Exception {

        new Wait("") {boolean until() {return false;}};session().open("/");
        new Wait("") {boolean until() {return false;}};session().click("id=btnLogin-button");       session().waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        for (int second = 0;; second++) {
            if (second >= 60) fail("timeout 'waitForTextPresent:Logoff' ");
            try { if (session().isTextPresent("Logoff")) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        new Wait("") {boolean until() {return false;}};session().click("id=btnUserLogout-button");
        new Wait("") {boolean until() {return false;}};session().click("id=yui-gen0-button");       session().waitForPageToLoad("30000");
  }
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    super.tearDown();
    closeSeleniumSession();
  }


}
```

[here](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/java/com/thoughtworks/selenium/Wait.html#Wait%28%29) is how I use Wait class. Please help me to understand this error.

Comment: Looks like they provide a wrong example in their own javadoc ;)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The lines with the problem are the two below

```
new Wait("") {boolean until() {return false;}};session().open("/");
new Wait("") {boolean until() {return false;}};session().click("id=btnLogin-button");
```

You try to override the `until` method which has `public` access in the `com.thoughtworks.selenium.Wait` class by a `until` method which is only package visible.

You cannot override a method and reduce visibility. You can only increase the visibility (e.g. overriding a `protected` method and making it `public`)

So the fix would be to add the `public` keyword to these methods

```
new Wait("") {public boolean until() {return false;}};session().open("/");
new Wait("") {public boolean until() {return false;}};session().click("id=btnLogin-button");
```

Comment: one second early than Keppil. Thanks both of you. :)

Comment: Yes, you mean I can only increase the visibility. overriding a protected method and making it public, but not package. I think package modifier can increase the visibility of protected one, am I right for this understanding?

Comment: @Richard no that is not correct. Protected methods are visible for all subclasses, also subclasses outside the package. So making it package visible would increase visibility for some cases (another class in the same package), but reduce visibility as well in other cases (subclass in another package).

Comment: Easily said, javac won't compile it, so it is not totally an expansion of visibility.